# AJAX File upload with PHP-CodeIgniter not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have been trying to upload an image with AJAX but somehow it's not working. CodeIgniter always throwing 'You have not selected any file'.
Thanks in advance.

Here's my Controller -

```
class Upload extends CI_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
    }

    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('upload/upload');
    }

    public function upload_file() {
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/Ajax/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|doc|txt';
        $config['max_size'] = 1024 * 8;

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $title=$this->input->post('title');

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
            echo $this->upload->display_errors()."<br>".$title;
        }
        else {
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            echo $data['file_name']." uploaded successfully";
        }
    }
}

/* end of file */
```

And here's the view

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX File Upload</title>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.js">    </script>
        <script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/js/AjaxFileUpload.js">    </script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#upload-form').submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (typeof FormData !== 'undefined') {
                        $.ajax({
                            url     :   '<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/upload/upload_file',
                            type    :   'POST',
                            data    :   FormData,
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                $("#result").html("Uploading, please wait....");
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("ERROR in upload");
                            },
                            success :   function(data) {
                                $('#result').html(data)
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Your browser doesn't support FormData API!");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

<body>
    <h1>Upload File</h1>
    <form method="post" action="" id="upload-form" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <p>
            <label for="title">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value="" autocomplete="off">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="userfile">File</label>
            <input type="file" name="userfile" id="userfile">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit">
    </form>

    <h2>Result</h2>
    <span id="result"></span>
</body>
```

I have tested in Firefox 43, IE11 & Chrome 43

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#upload-form').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                if (typeof FormData !== 'undefined') {
                    $.ajax({
                        url     :   '<?php echo base_url(); ?>upload/upload/upload_file',
                        type    :   'POST',
                         secureuri      :false,
                       fileElementId    :'userfile',
                        data    :   FormData,
                        beforeSend: function () {
                            $("#result").html("Uploading, please wait....");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("ERROR in upload");
                        },
                        success :   function(data) {
                            $('#result').html(data)
                        }
                    });
                }
                else {
                    alert("Your browser doesn't support FormData API!");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add xhr function in ajax request

```
$(document).on('submit','#form_id',function(){
   var formData = new FormData(this);
   $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var xhrobj = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();            
            return xhrobj;
        },
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$(document).on('submit','#form_id',function(){
   var formData = new FormData(this);
   $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data:formData,
        cache:false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
            console.log("success");
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(data){
            console.log("error");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

no plugin required for this, for easiness you can use ajaxForm jquery plugin and just use

```
$('#form-id').ajaxSubmit({
   // same config as ajax call but dont use data option right here
});
```

have a look on http://malsup.com/jquery/form/ to for more information about plugin

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("#upload-form").on('submit' ,function(){
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: new FormData(form[0]),
        dataType: 'json',
        method: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){


        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $.ajaxFileUpload instead $.ajax, this should work, if not please let me see your AjaxFileUpload.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $('#upload-form').submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (typeof FormData !== 'undefined') {

                       $.ajaxFileUpload({ 
                        url             :'./upload/upload_file/',                  
                        fileElementId   : 'userfile', //  your input file ID
                        dataType        : 'json',
                        // 
                        data            : {
                            'title'             : $('#title').val() // parse title input data
                        },
                            beforeSend: function () {
                                $("#result").html("Uploading, please wait....");
                            },
                            error: function () {
                                alert("ERROR in upload");
                            },
                            success :   function(data) {
                                $('#result').html(data)
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Your browser doesn't support FormData API!");
                    }
                });
            });
```

Comment: [ajaxFileUpload.js](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3qwftjgjlzq5eag/AjaxFileUpload.js?dl=0)

Comment: Replace your ajaxFileUpload with this [ajaxFileUpload.js] https://www.dropbox.com/s/b0a6lb8mtpxkp4w/ajaxFileUpload.js?dl=0